# My program doesn't show the compile result, Code about getting Self Number

Tags: c

definition of self number:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self_number

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int selfarr[10001];

int findselfnumber(int n)
{

    int a = n;
    do{
        a += n%10;
    }while((n/10) != 0);
    return a;       
}

int main(void)
{

    int i = 1;    
    for(; i++<=10000;)
        selfarr[findselfnumber(i)] = 1;
    for(; i++<=10000;)        
        if(selfarr[i]!=1) 
            printf("%d\n", i);
  
    return 0;   
}
```

I can't find what's wrong with my code, I think the algorithm was appropriate.
Please help me find out the error.
Thank you.

Comment: Format your code, please. And share your error message (what in the world is it that makes people think it's OK to jus say "my program doesn't compile"????)

Comment: Fix code indentation. You have an endless loop because you don't update the cycle variable `n`.

Comment: Sorry, but the code you posted is not C code. You are missing `{}`s in your for loop, and the for loop condition is a syntax error as far as I know. I think the best solution is : Reread a good C course, then start over.

Comment: Nope, @Programmer, braces are not required around single-statement `for` loop bodies such as the OP's, and whatever it is you think is wrong about the `for` loop conditions, isn't.  Perhaps those conditions would be clearer if spaces were inserted: `i++ <= 10000`, but the meaning is the same either way.

Comment: To see the "compile result" you have to compile it.  Have you done that? How?  Do you actually mean it shows no result on _execution_ perhaps, rather then compilation?

Comment: @JohnBollinger do you mean, `i++ <= 10000` is the same as `int i=1; i <= 10000; i++` ?

Comment: @Programmer : No he means it means the same with or without the spaces.  It is a non-idiomatic use of `for`, but not syntactically incorrrect.  the suntax of `for` in C is `for( <expression>; <expression>; <expression> ) <statement | statement-block>`  any valid expression is allowed in any part.  It is semantically very flexible, but open to abuse - I would call this an abuse.

Comment: @Programmer, as Clifford said.  Or to put it another way, it is allowed for any or all of the three clauses of a `for` loop's control statement to be empty.  Although `while` loops would have been more idiomatic, the OP's code is syntactically valid, as your compiler could have told you, and the `for` loops look like they accomplish reasonable tasks.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ok thanks, I learned something new then. It just looked absolutely wrong to me.

Comment: @Programmer And so it should.  It is horrible code.  Even the equivalent `while(i++ <= 10000)` is a bad idea. What is perhaps not obvious is the loop body the value `i` iterates from 1 to 10001.  It seems unlikely that this was intentional and is a semantic error caused by non-idiomatic code.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop:

```
do{
    a += n%10;
}while((n/10) != 0);
```

the variable `n` is loop invariant - it never changes so the condition never becomes true, so you are stuck in the loop indefinitely.

Given the link you included in your qyestion, I assume you are attempting to implement *F<sub>b</sub>(n)* as defined by:
[image]
I see no real attempt to correctly implement that formula.  Equally if you are attempting teh "selfness test" - the code is equally implausible.

Even if you get that working, this loop:

```
for(; i++<=10000;)        
    if(selfarr[i]!=1) 
        printf("%d\n", i);
```

will never iterate because at that point `i` is already equal to 10001 dure to the preceding loop.

I must say the omission of an initialiser statement and incrementing `i` in the conditional statement is both non-idiomatic and error prone.  Don't write weird code - simple idiomatic code is much simpler to debug.  If I had the first clue what it was you were trying to do, I'd tell you how to fix it!